# How to integrate Open UI5 in visual studio

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, sapui5

I want to use Open UI5 library on visual studio.
I have downloaded the source files from http://sap.github.io/openui5/download.html .
I want to integrate it with Visual Studio.
Can any one tell by using a example in asp.net MVC ?

**EDIT**
SO far what I have done is that I added the resource folder of Open UI5 into my MVC project by simply drag and drop.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question completely. Openui5 is just a frontend library with controls. How can you integrate it in an IDE? Just use it like a frontend library :D

Comment: @Aleksandrenko sir as I am new to MVC and OpenUI5 I want to use OpenUI5 in MVC. I know little basic of MVC, was creating some sample  through it but doesn't find any help how to work that's why I posted it so that some one can help me to use OpenUI5 with asp.net mVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for Visual Studio (not official) which provides templates: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/aabd3f1e-fd57-43f5-8dde-54dd0355defe

You may also have a look at this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cyc59RL-qgw